# in XSLT, what does <xsl:if test=".[foo or @bar]"> mean and what is the cross-browser solution?

Tags: xslt, cross-browser

XSL:

```
<xsl:if test=".[foo or @bar]">
    something
</xsl:if>
```

1. is it testing that if target is with 'foo' tag name or has a 'bar' attribute?
2. it works only in IE, I'm wondering if there is an error. What is the equivalent sentence but works cross-browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:if test=".[foo or @bar]">     
>   something 
> </xsl:if>
> ```

**In XSLT 1.0 this is syntactically invalid and produces an error**.

**In XSLT 2.0 this is equivalent to**:

```
 <xsl:if test="foo or @bar">     
   something 
 </xsl:if>
```

**The expression**:

```
foo or @bar
```

evaluates to `true()` exactly when the context node (current node) has a child element named `foo` *or* the context node has an attribute named `bar` (or both).

Otherwise this expression evaluates to `false()`.

Therefore, the above code snippet means: *If either of these conditions is true: the current node has a child element named `foo` or the current node has an attribute named `bar` -- then output the string "something"*

Comment: XSLT 2.0, so that's why there are inconsistencies among browsers. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @gfaceless: *All* browsers at present use only XSLT 1.0. Maybe the XSLT processor of IE6 has a bug. Anyway, all should accept `foo or @bar` -- this is the correction that you could make to ensure the same x-browser behavior. BTW, you may *accept* the most useful answer, by clicking on the check-mark next to it :)

Answer (score 2):

The syntax `.[x]` is not allowed in XSLT 1.0. It was allowed in early drafts of XSLT 1.0, and I suspect it was absent from the final version as a result of an oversight rather than being a deliberate design decision (and as already remarked, it was reinstated in XSLT 2.0). Because IE first shipped its XSLT processor before the 1.0 spec was finalized, it's possible that they support this syntax for backwards compatibility with those early drafts.

Answer (score 0):

It tests whether the current node has a child element named `foo` or has an attribute called `bar`. That is, if you change it to

```
<xsl:if test="foo or @bar">
```

The syntax you use is rejected in my xsl parser: `Invalid XPath expression
Unexpected token - "[foo or @bar]"`

The one I use should work cross-browser.
If you wish to select nodes that have name `foo` or a `bar` attribute, then use the following:

```
<xsl:if test="name()='foo' or @bar">
```

Comment: I thought it was an error, but IE6 is 'strong' enough to ignore that. Thanks for your detailed clarification.